# Jquery ui datepicker not working properly in second Dialog

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-ui-dialog

i'd appreciate your help with this one. I've been searching for a fix for hours now and I just can't get it to work.

I have two files "editor.php" and "functions.php".

So I got this Jquery UI datepicker, which I am initializing and giving the holding textfield an unique ID in the editor.php

```
$(function() {
     $('input[name=Date]').attr('id',   'Date' + '_' + $("#Id").val());

        $("#Date_" + $('#Id').val()).datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
            changeMonth: true,
            showWeek: true
        });
}
```

My Dialog opening function is in the functions.php

```
function openDialog()
    {    
        var customDialog = $('#customDialog').dialog( { 
            open: function () {             
                $('body').addClass('stop-scrolling');
                $('.ui-widget-overlay').addClass('custom-overlay');
                }, 
            beforeClose: function () { 
                $('body').removeClass('stop-scrolling');
                $('.ui-widget-overlay').removeClass('custom-overlay');
                }, 
            autoOpen: false, 
            modal: true,
            show: {
                effect: "fade", 
                duration: 400
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "fade",
                duration: 400
            }, 
        } );

        customDialog.load('editor.php');    

        customDialog.dialog("open");
    }
```

And also in that functions.php i got the div which is holding the Dialog

```
<div id="customDialog" title="Editor"></div>
```

My Dialog has a form in it which I am building in the editor.php. The Dialog and my form data Shows up properly. Now I have a datepicker on one of my textfields in that form which works fine within that Dialog.

Now i have a link in that Dialog, which opens another Dialog and Closes the old one, which works fine aswell. My Problem now is, that the datepicker will no longer Show up, but I am sure it is there, because i can click in it and press enter and the current date will Show up on that textfield.

I found out that my old dialogs aren't being closed properly and my datepicker is always bound to the date-textfield in my first Dialog (even if i can't see the Dialog anymore).

```
$("#customDialog").dialog('close');
```

this did not work : "cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'"  shows up. So i used following code which kinda worked (but I am sure it isn't being closed properly and is still somewhere hidden)

```
$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').click()
```

Changing z-index of datepicker-ui to something very high did not help

My question is: What is the proper way to Close a Dialog. I can't get `$("#customDialog").dialog('close');` to work

Please ask if anything is unclear. Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**
added missing apostrophe in customDialog.load('editor.php'); and edited question to make it more clear

Comment: Side note, you have a typo in `customDialog.load('editor.php);` (missing closing `'`)

Comment: Thanks, just a typo that happened while copy pasting my code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the solution to this. I hope it helps someone in need.
I am using Jquery 1.11.1 and it seems that there is a line of code missing in the jquery-ui.js file.
You need to add this one line to your jquery-ui.js in that specific place.
It will re-initialize your datepicker even if you don't refresh your page.

```
/* Initialise the date picker. */
    if (!$.datepicker.initialized) {
        $(document).mousedown($.datepicker._checkExternalClick)
        .find(document.body).append($.datepicker.dpDiv); // added line
        $.datepicker.initialized = true;
    }
```